# How to break a relation path, to two relations, inside a WHERE clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am making a Clojure DSL using the Java DSL for cypher.

```
MATCH 
(tom:`Person` {name: 'Tom Hanks'})-[:`ACTED_IN`]->(m)<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(coActors), 
(coActors)-[:`ACTED_IN`]->(m2)<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(cocoActors) 
WHERE 
(NOT (tom)-[:`ACTED_IN`]->()<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(cocoActors) AND tom <> cocoActors) 
RETURN cocoActors.name;
```

So far i choosed to not write big paths but break them all in triplets connected with
sharing variables like. Like SPARQL.

```
(:acted-in (?tom:Person :name "Tom Hanks") ?m)
(:acted-in ?coActors ?m)
```

The problem that i have is how to do the same in the WHERE relation, can someone write the same query but in the WHERE break the `` (tom)-[:`ACTED_IN`]->()<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(cocoActors) `` to 2 relations with a shared temp var, and use the operators in correct way to produce the same results?

If someone can write it in Cypher java DSL even better.
In general in Cypher writing long paths is optional or we can't do it in other way?Using triplets with variables is enough?

If possible i would want to write something like the bellow but i can't make it work, `and` complains that argument is `relationShip`

```
(run-query (q (:acted-in (?tom:Person :name "Tom Hanks") ?m)
              (:acted-in ?coActors ?m)
              (:acted-in ?coActors ?m2)
              (:acted-in ?cocoActors ?m2)
              ;;break in 2, this is the where condition
              ((not (and (:acted-in ?tom ?m3)
                         (:acted-in ?cocoActors ?m3))))))
```

There is no need you to write it in my DSL, if you write it in Cypher in 2 triplets i will be able to do it in my DSL also.

Comment: What do you mean by a "triplet"? And why is writing in triplets important?

Comment: i mean subject-relation-object, and making bigger paths by shared variables, like in the example, i broke the `(tom:`Person` {name: 'Tom Hanks'})-[:`ACTED_IN`]->(m)<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(coActors)` of the match to 2 "triplets" sharing the m variable. I want to do the same for the WHERE clause, break it to 2.

Comment: But your example is really a "quintuplet", not 2 triplets. So, maybe writing in triplets is not really important?

Comment: in the DSL that i make, i can only use triplets, subject-relation-object (with properties), so i have to break it or change my DSL to allow paths, if its not possible to write all paths in triplets with shared variables, i will have to change the DSL. Like SPARQL that allows only triples, i follow the SPARQL way because i like it more i think

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a `WHERE` clause cannot introduce new variables, so the `()` in your `WHERE` clause would usually not be replaceable by `(m3)` unless `m3` was already defined earlier in the query. *But since `m3` is supposed to be a nonexistent node, you can't do that either.*

However, neo4j 4.0 introduced [EXISTS subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#existential-subqueries), so you *can* do this (and `m3` only lives in the subquery):

```
MATCH 
  (tom:`Person` {name: 'Tom Hanks'})-[:`ACTED_IN`]->(m)<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(coActors), 
  (coActors)-[:`ACTED_IN`]->(m2)<-[:`ACTED_IN`]-(cocoActors) 
WHERE
  tom <> cocoActors AND
  NOT EXISTS {
    (tom)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m3)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cocoActors)
  }
RETURN cocoActors.name;
```

Alternatively, you can just continue to use `()` in `WHERE` clauses whenever you want to represent a node that should not exist. Even though your DSL may require a variable name, that does not mean that you must also have a variable name in Cypher.

Comment: thank you for helping me, i think i need to pause my DSL for now and learn Cypher, better. do you know if the cypher java dsl,  is complete? Or if there is a plan to make it complete?
Because i use the java dsl so i am curious if i can really replace cypher with it.

Comment: If you are referring to [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl), it looks pretty complete, but I have never used it. [Here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/cypher-dsl/2023.3.0/) is the manual. Maybe you can ask one of [the developers](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/cypher-dsl/2023.3.0/project-info/team.html) for more info.